# How to fetch large data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
Table Query:
Id     Subject    LangId    replyCount    created_at

Table userLogin:
Id     userId     Fname    Lanme    created_at
```

I am using select query with inner join to fetch data from mysql but it takes about 5sec to fetch 10000 records,I have also used indexing on coulmn LangId,Can you suggest any other way to make it run faster?

```
select q.id,q.Subject,u.userid,q.replyCount,DATE_FORMAT(q.created_at,'%d-%b-%Y') 
from query as q INNER JOIN userLogin as u on q.userId = u.id where q.LangId = ?
```

Comment: I am newbie to php,mysql and About the deleted question somebody voted down to that question and It seems not many people reply to voted down question.

Comment: @neel.1708 Simply improve your question instead! For instance, add outputs of "EXPLAIN select q.id,q.Subject,u.userid, ...", "SHOW CREATE TABLE query" and "SHOW CREATE TABLE userLogin". Otherwise, people won't be able to be of much help.

Comment: Yes ,will do that from next time.Thanks sfussenegger.

Comment: @neel.1708 - better to do it this time if you want a sensible answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do not select 10000 records at once.

To do a pagination, you have to run the same query on the every page with LIMIT clause, fetching the only records required on the page.

Comment: If i show first 50 records on the page and user hits next how to fetch next 50 records and after that he clicks on and previous then how to show previous 50 using limit.

Comment: To do simple maths: 10.000 rows of (let's assume) 255 byte yield 2.550.000 byte or about 2MB. That's not very much, at least no reason for 5 seconds of execution time. I just did a similar query on a DB within less than 0.1s. Unfortunately, it's pretty much impossible to find another reason without any other information.

Comment: @neel.1708 LIMIT ($pageNumber * $itemsPerPage), $itemsPerPage

Comment: @neel.1708 @NathanQ assumes that $pageNumber is 0 based (i.e. your first page is 0). If your first page is 1, do `LIMIT (($pageNumber-1) * $itemsPerPage), $itemsPerPage`

Answer (score 0):

Use paging if u have larg records, and if you have complex queries then make a view table, then simply fetch record from view with single select statement..

Hope you understand..

Comment: yes,Will selecting from view be faster than complex select query ?